# Best practice for backbonejs nested models and collections

Tags: backbone.js

I am new to backbone, and confusing about the right way to use model and collections.

I have two nested model `Parent` and `child` in one to many relationship. As backbonejs suggested, I have following code:

```
var Child = Backbone.Model.extend({});
Child.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

var Parent = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.children = new Child.Collection;
  }
});

var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  var parent = this.model
  this.children = parent.children;
});
```

This works fine, until I start need editing single child by "server id".
So I end up with three solutions, and none of them looks right to me:

1, get the existing instance by request a new instance from server:

```
var child = getFromServerById(id);
var parent = parentCollection.get(child.get('parentId'));
child = parent.children.get(child.id);
```

2, have to loop through all parent (when their is more than one ancestor, this becomes really terrible):

```
var child;
var parent = parentCollection.find(function(parent){ 
  child = parent.children.get(childId);
  return child;
});
```

3, Create a global cache for every model. (this is currently I am going with, but it require me to keep maintain the globalCache every time I add/delete objects)

```
var child = globalCache['child'].get(id);
```

So I'd like to know if there are some standard pattern to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: use backbone-relational

Answer (score 2, accepted):

relation to manage nested models.

https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational